dates and overlapping dates function
I am trying to create a function that takes overlapping periods into account in this ordered data by id, start_ins, rxdate:
dt <- data.table(
    id = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
    start_ins = as.Date(c("2000-10-12", "2000-03-31", "2000-03-31", "2000-01-11", "2000-01-11", "2000-01-11")),
    rxdate = as.Date(c("2010-01-04", "2010-03-30", "2010-04-08", "2003-12-29", "2004-01-12", "2004-03-10")),
    amount = c(30, 28, 100, 60, 1, 10),
    rx_end = as.Date(c("2010-02-03", "2010-04-27", "2010-07-17", "2004-02-27", "2004-01-13", "2004-03-20"))
)

In this set, observations are grouped by id and start_ins. People also purchase Rx on a date and the number of pills (amount). rx_end is
[, rx_end := rxdate + amount]

However, if you look closely, you will find that rx_end for line 2 comes after rxdate for line 3. In this case, there is an overlap between rxdate line 3 and end of previous prescription. I want to assume that a person finished a rx before starting a new rx. In this case rxdate for line 3 should start the day after rx_end of line 2 AND rx_end for line 3 should be updated to take into account the new rxdate in line 3. Same logic applies for lines 4 and 5. In this case, the new data set would look something like this:
dt1 <- data.table(
    id = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
    start_ins = as.Date(c("2000-10-12", "2000-03-31", "2000-03-31", "2000-01-11", "2000-01-11", "2000-01-11")),
    rxdate = as.Date(c("2010-01-04", "2010-03-30", "2010-04-28", "2003-12-29", "2004-02-28", "2004-03-10")),
    amount = c(30, 28, 100, 60, 1, 10),
    rx_end = as.Date(c("2010-02-03", "2010-04-27", "2010-08-06", "2004-02-27", "2004-02-29", "2004-03-20"))
)

I tried writing this function using data.table:
overlapper <- function (dt){
dt[,{
prev_end_date <- shift(rx_end, 1, type = "lag")

for (i in 2:.N){
if(!is.na(prev_end_date[i-1]) & prev_end_date >= dt[i, rxdate]){
dt[i, rxdate := prev_end_date[i-1] +1]
dt[i, rx_end := rxdate + amount]
}
prev_end_date[i] <- dt[i, rx_end]
}
return(dt)}, by = .(id, start_ins)]}

Keep in mind that some people have only one observation, so these should not be taken into account and that is why I am doing a grouped operation by id and start_ins.
I always want to look at line n and compare it to n-1 to update line n ONLY if there is an overlap. If there is no over lap, I would keep the line as is and move on to the next line.

Does your data really require a sequential approach? Your toy data looks like it can be done without.

You can do this using data.table::shift().

Calculate the duration of each prescription and put it in rx_days.
If there's an overlap with the previous prescription (by ID) move the start date to the day after the previous end date.
Make sure we never replace the first row in a group (we need to state this explicitly given your note in the comment about the change from < to <=).
Adjust the end dates based on the duration and the new start dates and remove the temporary variable rx_days.
Continue until this is stable.

Here are steps 1-4, which work with your sample data:
dt[, c("rxdate", "rx_end") := {
    i <- seq(.N) # never replace first row
    shifted_rx_end <- shift(rx_end, 1, fill = rxdate[1])
    shift_dates <- fifelse(i == 1, FALSE, rxdate <= shifted_rx_end)
    rxdate <- fifelse(shift_dates, shifted_rx_end + 1, rxdate)
    rx_end[shift_dates] <- rxdate[shift_dates] + amount[shift_dates]
    .(rxdate, rx_end)
}, .(id, start_ins)]

identical(dt, dt1)
# [1] TRUE

However, imagine this new data frame:
      id  start_ins     rxdate amount     rx_end
   <num>     <Date>     <Date>  <num>     <Date>
1:     1 2000-10-12 2010-01-04     30 2010-02-03
2:     2 2000-03-31 2010-03-30     28 2010-04-27
3:     2 2000-03-31 2010-04-08    100 2010-07-17
4:     2 2000-03-31 2010-07-20     10 2010-07-30 # new row
5:     2 2000-03-31 2010-08-15     17 2010-09-01 # new row
6:     3 2000-01-11 2003-12-29     60 2004-02-27
7:     3 2000-01-11 2004-01-12      1 2004-01-13
8:     3 2000-01-11 2004-03-10     10 2004-03-20

If we apply this approach, row 3 will update correctly but row 4 will not reflect the changes in row 3, and so does not trigger what should be an update in row 5.
To resolve this we can put it in a recursive function that calls itself until there are no more changes:
shift_dates <- function(dt, grp = c("id", "start_ins")) {
    old_state <- dt[, .(rxdate, rx_end)]
    dt[, c("rxdate", "rx_end") := {
        i <- seq(.N) # never replace first row
        shifted_rx_end <- shift(rx_end, 1, fill = rxdate[1])
        shift_dates <- fifelse(i == 1, FALSE, rxdate <= shifted_rx_end)
        rxdate <- fifelse(shift_dates, shifted_rx_end + 1, rxdate)
        rx_end[shift_dates] <- rxdate[shift_dates] + amount[shift_dates]
        .(rxdate, rx_end)
    }, grp]

    if (identical(dt[, .(rxdate, rx_end)], old_state)) {
        return(dt)
    }
    shift_dates(dt)
}

This means the changes from previous rows will propagate until complete:
shift_dates(dt2)
      id  start_ins     rxdate amount     rx_end
   <num>     <Date>     <Date>  <num>     <Date>
1:     1 2000-10-12 2010-01-04     30 2010-02-03
2:     2 2000-03-31 2010-03-30     28 2010-04-27
3:     2 2000-03-31 2010-04-28    100 2010-08-06
4:     2 2000-03-31 2010-08-07     10 2010-08-17 # change propagates
5:     2 2000-03-31 2010-08-18     17 2010-09-04 # change propagates
6:     3 2000-01-11 2003-12-29     60 2004-02-27
7:     3 2000-01-11 2004-02-28      1 2004-02-29
8:     3 2000-01-11 2004-03-10     10 2004-03-20

New data
dt2 <- data.table(
    id = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
    start_ins = as.Date(c("2000-10-12", "2000-03-31", "2000-03-31", "2000-03-31", "2000-03-31", "2000-01-11", "2000-01-11", "2000-01-11")),
    rxdate = as.Date(c("2010-01-04", "2010-03-30", "2010-04-08", "2010-07-20", "2010-08-15", "2003-12-29", "2004-01-12", "2004-03-10")),
    amount = c(30, 28, 100, 10, 17, 60, 1, 10),
    rx_end = as.Date(c("2010-02-03", "2010-04-27", "2010-07-17", "2010-07-30", "2010-09-01", "2004-02-27", "2004-01-13", "2004-03-20"))
)


Thank you for your answer. I have two questions:
1 - In some instances, I might have rxdate that is equal to the previous end_date. I still need to push the rxdate to the day after the previous end_date since it is technically and overlap. In your code rxdate < shift(rx_end, 1, fill = rxdate[1]), what would happen if I were to do this instead rxdate <= shift(rx_end, 1, fill = rxdate[1])
2 - Is it possible to run your code grouping by id and start_ins ? some people have the same id but different start_ins and it is important to run your code for grouped data.

@Youknowme see my edit. The function can take whichever grouping columns you like. We also need to add a special check for one row groups if you're looking at equality otherwise if we fill from the first end date of the group we'll get in trouble.

Use SamR's answer (better approach, much faster, your data is already storead as data.table)! This answer is intended to explicitly demonstrate the for-loops if a sequential approach is indeed needed.
Base R
for (i in seq(nrow(l))[-1]) {
  t0 = l[["rx_end"]][i-1] # pre-allocation
  if (t0 - l[["rxdate"]][i] >= 0) {
    u = t0 + 1 # <- update ->
    l[["rxdate"]][i] = u
    l[["rx_end"]][i] = u + l[["amount"]][i]
    }
  }

where l is a data.frame. This is the inner loop running over the observations (rows) of each id. We also need an outer loop which iterates over each id. A convenient approach is to split dt on id and start_ins and iterate over the resulting list of data.frames with lapply().
To collect results we use
# combine results 
unlist2d = \(l) do.call("rbind", l) |> `row.names<-`(NULL)

All togehter
dt0 = as.data.frame(dt)
dt0 =
  lapply(split(dt0, ~id+start_ins, drop = TRUE), \(l) 
         if (nrow(l) > 1) { # more than one row per group
           for (i in seq(nrow(l))[-1]) {
             t0 = l[["rx_end"]][i-1]
             if (t0 - l[["rxdate"]][i] >= 0) {
               u = t0 + 1 
               l[["rxdate"]][i] = u
               l[["rx_end"]][i] = u + l[["amount"]][i] }
             }
           l
           } 
         else l
         ) |> 
  unlist2d() |> 
  sort_by(~id+start_ins+rxdate)

giving
> identical(as.data.table(dt0), dt1)
[1] TRUE

Assumption: dt is ordered by id+start_ins+rxdate.

FYI this didn't work with my modified sample data because I didn't realise the amount column was meaningful and was separately calculating it as rx_days. But you're using the column so I see now that was unnecessary - I've updated the sample data and removed the duplication of the column in my code. Both answers output the same values.
